# Fetch Data from database table based on dropdown user selection

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have table called cusmain.

Table contains price information about customer. Table contains fields like

```
c_id
c_name
c_email
c_phone
c_totalsales
c_last transaction
contact_last
```

I have added some code and created drop down which allow me to select id.

```html
db = JFactory::getDBO();
//Pass in query
$query = "SELECT * FROM  cusmain"; 


//Run it
$db -> setQuery($query);

$c_id = $db -> loadObjectList();
```

However, I want to ensure when , I select id from the drop down , it automatically fetch few data-points from database table based on my drop-down selection (like totalsales ,  last transaction ,  last fields   in the my  Joomla module).